# Is it possible to share StarCraft with another Battle.net account?

Tags: battle.net

I have purchased the first two SC2 games, and would like my son to be able to play.  I am currently installing them on his computer from my Battle.net account.  Is there a way for him to play that game (which I have a physical copy of, though he does not have an optical drive) using his account, without having to re-purchase the game?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, this is not allowed, per their support:

[image]

Comment: Note that if you want to play together, he can play with the starter edition as long as he's in a group with you.

Answer (score 1):

No. Blizzard is very strict about this stuff. A game belongs to only one battle.net account. He can log in to your account to play, but you can't be online at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

While your son can play with you using the StarCraft 2 Starter Edition (free) while in the same group (thanks to @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft for stating this out), you can't really transfer your key without using some tricks like [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/76303/87186), which consists of lying etc, so I would not recommend doing such thing.

If you are thinking about sharing your account with your son, I recommend you to think again as the [EULA](http://us.blizzard.com/en-us/company/legal/eula.html) states that you can't share your account.

> 2.A.vii: All Accounts. Note that Blizzard owns all Accounts, and that all use of an Account shall inure to Blizzard’s benefit. **Blizzard does not recognize the transfer of Accounts**. You may not purchase, sell, gift or trade any Account, or offer to purchase, sell, gift, or trade any Account, and any such attempt shall be null and void and **may result in the forfeiture of the Account**;
>
> 1.A.iv: When you create an Account, you will be required to select a unique username and password (collectively referred to hereunder as “Login Information”). You may not use your real name as the password for the Account, and **you cannot share the Account or the Login Information with anyone**, unless the terms of this Agreement allow it.

Comment: Actually, I believe there is a provision somewhere that permits him to share his account with 1 minor that he is the legal guardian of. At least, I know the WoW Terms of Use have such a provision.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs [yep, but only wow](http://eu.blizzard.com/en-gb/company/legal/wow_tou.html) "for one (1) minor child for whom you are a parent or guardian and whom you have authorized to use the account you create on the Service." "[you will not] let any third person (except for a minor for whom you opened the Account) play on your Account including, but not limited to [...]", **but it says that the account must be owned by minor and not by the guardian ("for a minor for whom you opened the Account").**

Comment: @NateKerkhofs Just checked the generic battle.net tos as they apparently combined the old SC2 tos with bnet tos ([this](http://us.blizzard.com/en-us/company/legal/sc2eula.html) redirects to [this](http://us.blizzard.com/en-us/company/legal/eula.html)), and it doesn't allow such thing for sc2.

Comment: I searched that for "Guardian". Paragraph 1.A.iv mentions "minor children may utilize an Account established by their parent or legal guardian", which doesn't state that the account should be registered on the name of the ward.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs still it is somewhat of a gray area (the sentence I stated might be used by blizzard if they really want to ban you), however this doesn't affect this question as there is no such thing that applies to SC2.